# How to modify cells in column conditionally in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a csv dataset which for whatever reason has an extra asterisk (*) at the end of some names. I am trying to remove them, but I'm having trouble. I just want to replace the name in the case where it ends with a *, otherwise keep it as-is.

I have tried a couple variations of the following, but with little success.

```
 import pandas as pd
 people = pd.read_csv("people.csv")
 people.loc[people["name"].str[-1] == "*"]] = people["name"].str[:-1]
```

Here I am getting the following error:

```
 ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable
```

I understand why this is wrong, but I'm not sure how else to reference the values I want to change.

I could instead do something like:

```
 starred = people.loc[people["name"].str[-1] == "*"] 
 starred["name"] = starred["name"].str[:-1]
```

I get a warning here, but this kind of works. The problem is that it only contains the previously starred people, not all of them.

I'm kind of new to this, so apologies if this is simple. I feel like it shouldn't be too hard, there should be some function to do this, but I don't know what it is.

Comment: can't you use [str.strip](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html)? `df['name'].str.strip("*")`. You need to use `rstrip` to strip only at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax for [`pd.DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) needs to include a column label:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['John*', 'Rose', 'Summer', 'Mark*']})

df.loc[df['name'].str[-1] == '*', 'name'] = df['name'].str[:-1]

print(df)

     name
0    John
1    Rose
2  Summer
3    Mark
```

If you only specify the first part of the indexer, you will be filtering by row label only and return a dataframe. You cannot assign a series to a dataframe.

Comment: Thank you so much, it seems to work! This is cool functionality that I wasn't aware of since I'm new to this.

Comment: @Glu, you can expriment with `df['name'].str.contains('\*$')` too.